# Placing a UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I have an Activity Indicator and it shows in the middel. How do I place it in the left top corner of the view?

```
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func show() {
             UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

            self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center

            self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

            self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle =  UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray

            self.checkView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)

            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: just comment the line `self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center` and you are ready to go

Comment: When I comment the line out, for some reason the indicator doesn't show at all

Comment: I got the issue. It just got behind the navigation bar (in my case ) just need to update the frame from `UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))` to `UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))`

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem :D

Comment: If you like you can just change the `self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center` line to `self.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 180)`

Answer (score 1):

**I have Read your Question :**

If I am not Wrong i have done following Setup to support your USE-Case:

1. I have used the already available view for showing the Loader i.e. Main View.
2. Now I have implemented the following code to set Activity Indicator at top left corner in `viewDidLoad` You Can use in function also.

   ```
   self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
   self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
   self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
   self.checkView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
   self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
   ```
3. Dont Forget to add `var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()` at the Top and also Make Sure there are no colour combination Issues.

Following all this steps Perfectly , I am Getting an Activity Indicator at Top Left of my Main View.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the added `UIActivityIndicatorView`'s center needs to be set properly. Just change the `self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center` line to `self.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 180)`

This will solve your issue.

**Note: You can set value if `y` to any value you want.**